# apache Impala for other hadoop cluster apart from CDH

Tags: apache, impala

I just visited the impala site .
When I try to install it, its taking me to cloudera site.
I want to know ,has anyone installed Apache Impala(Incubating) with Non CDH Hadoop cluster?
Can anybody share the steps/guide ?

Answer (score 0):

CDH is not a prerequisite for Impala (eg, Impala also runs on S3 and MapR-FS), so it should run on stock HDFS. But that config is not tested by Cloudera and there are no docs for it.

With Impala now in ASF incubation, Impala-on-stock-HDFS scenarios may become more common.